# Validação de CNPJ em PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, validator

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe ou conhece um validador de CNPJ em PL/SQL Oracle.

Precisava que o usuário colocasse o valor em um "dbms_output.put_line" e chamasse um validador. Já consegui um validador que vou colocar a baixo mas infelizmente não acho essa solução onde o usuário coloque o CNPJ e depois é chamado o validador.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CNPJ
  (p_cgc     IN CHAR)
   RETURN    BOOLEAN
IS
   m_total     NUMBER   :=  0;
   m_digito    NUMBER   :=  0;
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
     m_total := m_total + substr(p_cgc,i,1) * (6 - i);
 END LOOP;

 FOR i IN 5..12 LOOP
     m_total := m_total + substr(p_cgc,i,1) * (14 - i);
 END LOOP;

 m_digito := 11 - mod(m_total,11);

 IF m_digito > 9 THEN
    m_digito := 0;
 END IF;

 IF m_digito != substr(p_cgc,13,1) THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
 END IF;

 m_digito := 0;
 m_total  := 0;

 FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
     m_total := m_total + substr(p_cgc,i,1) * (7 - i);
 END LOOP;

 FOR i IN 6..13 LOOP
     m_total := m_total + substr(p_cgc,i,1) * (15 - i);
 END LOOP;

 m_digito := 11 - mod(m_total,11);

 IF m_digito > 9 THEN
    m_digito := 0;
 END IF;

 IF m_digito != substr(p_cgc,14,1) THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
 END IF;

 RETURN TRUE;
end;
```

Comment: Uma solução é colocar o validador em uma trigger gerando erro para valores inválidos.

Answer (score 2):

Basta você criar uma *trigger* para isso, quando houver um *insert* ou um *update* o próprio oracle valida se a função retorna verdadeiro ou falso.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_VALIDAR_CNPJ
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON [OWNER].[TABELA]

BEGIN
   IF [NOME_FUNCAO] THEN
           -- CNPJ VALIDO, SÓ DAR CONTINUIDADE NO PROCESSO
       ELSE
           -- CNPJ ESTÁ INVALIDO, ENTÃO APARECE A MENSAGEM DE ERRO!
           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'CNPJ inválido');
   END IF;

END;
```

Como não conheço o nome do owner, tabela e o nome da sua função, então não consigo deixar 100% correto, mas o caminho para funcionar é esse.

Comment: A trigger deveria ser de BEFORE.